# CSS JS Tabs - not hiding curren content if click another tab,

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this tabs mostly made with CSS, but I'm building it dynamically using a CMS, in that case the CSS is not enough to hide/show all the elements, so I made a JS.

It's working well displaying the content tabs once it is selected but it's not hiding the current content to display the new one, so it's just adding the new selected content under the one that already exist

Please feel free to run the snippet to see how it's working, I don't know if I'm making it too complicate but any advice and help will be more than welcome.

Thank you!

```js
/*this code is to identify the checked tab and display the content*/
var getAllDataInput = document.querySelectorAll('[data-input]');
for (let i = 0, len = getAllDataInput.length; i < len; i++) {

    let getSingleDataInput = getAllDataInput[i];
    let tabSelected = getAllDataInput[i].defaultChecked;
    if (tabSelected === true) {
        var DataInputValue = getSingleDataInput.dataset.input;
        var findDataSetMatch = document.querySelector('[data-section="' + DataInputValue + '"]');
        findDataSetMatch.style.display = "block";
    }
}

/*this is the function that is called on click, it will find the Tab the related Content and display it */
function hideTab(tabNumber) {
    let lastSelected = null;
    let checkTab = document.querySelector('[data-input="' + tabNumber + '"]');
    let contentTab = document.querySelector('[data-section="' + tabNumber + '"]');
  
    if (checkTab.checked === true) {
        contentTab.style.display = "block";
    }
    
    /*If another tab is selected I need to hide the current content and display the new one!*/
}
```

```css
    .tabsWrapper {
      margin: 5rem 1rem;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
    }
    .tab-content {
        display: none;
        padding: 20px 0 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .tab-title {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab-label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 0 -1px;
        padding: 15px 25px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-align: center;
        color: #bbb;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
    }
    .tab-label:hover {
        color: #888;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .tab-title:checked + label {
        color: #555;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-top: 2px solid orange;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="tabsWrapper">
/*FIRST TABS*/
    <input id="tab11" type="radio" name="tabs1" class="tab-title" data-input="11"  onClick="hideTab(11)" checked>
    <label for="tab11" class="tab-label">Title A</label>

    <input id="tab12" type="radio" name="tabs1" class="tab-title" data-input="12"  onClick="hideTab(12)">
    <label for="tab12" class="tab-label">Title B</label>

/*FIRST CONTENT*/
    <section id="ctab11" class="tab-content" data-section="11">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="ctab12" class="tab-content" data-section="12">
      <p>Invidunt menandri duo at, at everti prompta eos.</p>
    </section>

  </div>

  <div class="tabsWrapper">
/*SECOND TABS*/
    <input id="tab21" type="radio" name="tabs2" class="tab-title" data-input="21" onClick="hideTab(21)" checked>
    <label for="tab21" class="tab-label">Title A</label>

    <input id="tab22" type="radio" name="tabs2" class="tab-title" data-input="22"  onClick="hideTab(22)">
    <label for="tab22" class="tab-label">Title B</label>

/*SECOND CONTENT*/
    <section id="ctab21" class="tab-content" data-section="21">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    </section>
    <section id="ctab22" class="tab-content" data-section="22"> 
      <p>Invidunt menandri duo at, at everti prompta eos.</p>
    </section>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add an onClick event to the input tag to connect it to your js function. Then write a Js function that changes the style attribute of that tag that you want to change.

```
<style>
  #ctab21 {
    display: block;
    color: blue;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div>Hide text:</div>

  <!-- onclick attribute connects hideTab function to input tag -->
  <input id="tab21" type="checkbox" onClick="hideTab()">

  <section>

    <!-- hidden text to be displayed -->
    <p id="ctab21">This text will become hidden</p>

  </section>
</body>

<script>
  function hideTab() {

    // get the checkbox; id ="tab21"
    let checkBox = document.getElementById("tab21");

    // get the p tag; id ="ctab21"
    let text = document.getElementById("ctab21");

    // If the checkbox is checked, hide the text
    if (checkBox.checked == false) {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp

Comment: Dominic thank to your comment and your idea I made some modifications and  make it work, but I have one last thing to do, I'll change the question with the new update, hope you can help me, cheers mate!